# How to search for a word in an array and perform tasks?

Tags: php, arrays

I'm trying to search $states with the value `Mississippi Alabama Texas Massachusetts Kansas`. The script should perform the following tasks:

1. Search for a word in $states that ends in xas. Store this word in element 0 of an array named $statesArray.
2. Search for a word in $states that begins with k and ends in s. Perform a case-insensitive comparison. Store this word in element 1 of $statesArray.
3. Search for a word in $states that begins with M and ends in s. Store this element in element 2 of the array.
4. Search for a word in $states that ends in a. Store this word in element 3 of the array.
5. Search for a word in $states at the beginning of the string that starts with M. Store this word in element 4 of the array.
6. Output the array $statesArray to the screen.

   ```
   <html>
     <body>
     <?php

   $statesA = "Mississippi Alabama Texas Massachusetts Kansas". 
   $statesArray = array();

    foreach($statesA as $state) {
    if(preg_match( '/xas$/', ($state)))
    $statesArray[0] = ($state);
     }

    foreach($statesA as $state) {
    if(preg_match('/^k.*s$/i', ($state)))
    $statesArray[1] = ($state);
   }

    foreach($statesA as $state) {
   if(preg_match('/^M.*s$/', ($state)))
    $statesArray[2] = ($state);
    }

      foreach($statesA as $state) {
   if(preg_match('/a$/', ($state)))
    $statesArray[3] = ($state);
   }

    foreach($statesA as $state) {
    if(preg_match('/^M/', ($state)))
   $statesArray[4] = ($state);
   }

    foreach ( $statesArray as $element => $value )
    print( "Element $element of statesArray is $value <br />");


        print( "</p>" );
    ?><!-- end PHP script -->
   ```

The problem is that I'm not getting any output.

Answer (score 1):

$statesA is a string, not an array. So looping over it isn't doing anything.

Try using `$statesA = array('Mississippi', 'Alabama', 'Texas', 'Massachusetts', 'Kansas');` instead.

Answer (score 0):

`explode` method can also be used to break the sentence and convert it into an `array` if **$states** isn't an `array`.
Have a look at the code below.

```
    <?php
    $states = "Mississippi Alabama Texas Massachusetts Kansas";
    $statesArray = [];
    $states1 = explode(' ',$states);

    foreach($states1 as $state) {
        if(preg_match( '/xas$/', ($state)))
            $statesArray[0] = ($state);
    }
    foreach($states1 as $state) {
        if(preg_match('/^k.*s$/i', ($state)))
            $statesArray[1] = ($state);
    }
    foreach($states1 as $state) {
        if(preg_match('/^M.*s$/', ($state)))
            $statesArray[2] = ($state);
    }
    foreach($states1 as $state) {
        if(preg_match('/a$/', ($state)))
            $statesArray[3] = ($state);
    }
    foreach($states1 as $state) {
        if(preg_match('/^M/', ($state)))
            $statesArray[4] = ($state);
    }
    foreach ( $statesArray as $element => $value ){
        print( $value." is the element ". $element."<br/>");
    }
    ?>
```

**Output**
    
Texas is the element 0
    
Kansas is the element 1
    
Massachusetts is the element 2
    
Alabama is the element 3
    
Massachusetts is the element 4